# What are the main differences between MVVM and MVC in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, model-view-controller, mvvm

I'd like your inputs on what are the main differences between a MVVM project and a MVC project. I know the basic principles of MVVM and MVC but i'd like to know more technically about their difference in a WPF project.

Comment: My opinion is they are largely the same.  MVVM doesn't always explicitly define a controller for interacting with business logic (sometimes the view model will fill this void in less granular architectures), but it does provide the view model to facilitate things like two way binding.  MVC explicitly defines the controller to bridge the gap to business logic/view.  That being said MVC can and will often use view models as well.  In my opinion they both come down to style/granularity.

Comment: MVVM and MVC are design patterns, there isn't much different on a technical level other than the design principles. This is a very broad question and has probably been answered in detail on [many](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/) [other](https://discventionstech.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/mvc-vs-mvp-vs-mvvm/) [websites](http://www.rachelappel.com/comparing-the-mvc-and-mvvm-patterns-along-with-their-respective-viewmodels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers here talk about some of the benefits of MVVM, but I feel they fail to answer the question. I believe you're asking a philosophical question about the difference between MVC and MVVM.

In my experience, the Controller in MVC is responsible for triggering state changes on the View and Model. For example, your View might have a function like this:

```
public void SetupListBox(List<string> items) {...}
```

Or something even more monolithic, where lots of bits of information are provided at once:

```
public void SetupForm(string name, List<string> listItems, string selectedItem) {...}
```

The Controller will explicitly call this type of method to trigger the state change, and the View (in this case) will change its state within the method.

With MVVM, the ViewModel publicly exposes the state of the view, usually at a granular level:

```
public string Name { get {...} set {...} }
public List<string> ListItems { get {...} set {...} }
public string SelectedItem { get {...} set {...} }
```

The ViewModel also is responsible for notifying the View that a relevant state change has occurred. WPF uses INotifyPropertyChanged for this.

One way to think about it is that the ViewModel abstractly represents the state that SHOULD be present in the View. Whether that state is actually reflected in the view depends on how well you've implemented your architecture.

Note that MVC and MVVM are not competing patterns. With MVVM, you still need logic to drive the state changes. The key difference is where that state lives. It's often easiest to put all that state change driving logic directly in the ViewModel. Larger applications may require an MVVMC architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The most significant difference I see is the emphasis on the ability to 'switch out parts' using MVVM.  The idea is that the Model doesn't know about the ModelView and similarly the ModelView doesn't know about the View.  So if you completely re-design the View, the ModelView is unaffected.

With MVC it's likely that each of your inter-component references will go both ways (the Model will know about the Controller and vice versa).  This helps with interoperability of components but makes it difficult for any one piece to exist independently of the other two.  If you want to change your View you'll probably have to make proportional changes to the other two components.

With MVVM the model should be able to just do its thing with the data, oblivious to whether anyone outside its existence cares what it does.  The ModelView should be able to leverage all the cool stuff the Model is doing and make the data consumable to outside resources, but should be otherwise oblivious about how the end user will do the consuming.  Finally, the View knows about the ModelView and can get from it whatever it needs to customize the experience for its user.

The two big selling points are that you can switch out the View (nearly) seamlessly.  The ModelView knows nothing of the View so it runs regardless.  How the View plugs into the ModelView is entirely up to the View.  The other point is that you can unit test the Model and ModelView in relative isolation.  You don't need to initialize a View component to run it.

Although long and somewhat dense, this is a good read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: This is all fairly opinionated stuff, but I've never seen an MVC design where the model was aware of the Controller. Is there a platform or framework where this is common?

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are architectural patterns, the older is MVC, then comes MVP (Model View Presenter) and from MVP inherits MVVM.

If you implement MVVM in your WPF app, your code should be more decoupled because the view-logic should be implemented in a viewmodel class that can be rehused because is independent of the view. Thanks to the capabilities of WPF you can control your view's behavior through your viewmodels, where you expose observable data that can notify to the view when something has changed (but the viewmodel doesn't  know what is the data source), and commands where you implement the actions that tell the view what to do in response of user interactions (but the viewmodel doesn't know nothing about the view).

In other types of app like Asp.Net Web Forms or Windows Forms, the only way how we achieve this is writing the "code behind", where we control the users interactions and put the presentation logic, this is normally using MVP and MVC, in this way you have more code that depends of the UI and a simple UI change can break more code.